The similar-question panel is sometimes missing on Stack Exchange
The similar-question panel is sometimes missing on Stack Exchange. This makes it much harder for me to find old posts of mine or others' related posts. Is there any way to solve this?


I tried refreshing the page but it still wouldn't pop up.

Ahh, sorry, I'd tried on the wrong English site. When I try on English Language Learners, it doesn't pop-up, so I can reproduce this there. It's possible that that site may not have that facility turned on - I wouldn't know as I've not asked there before, and your profile shows no posts on that site. It doesn't seem to be a network-wide issue, so perhaps this question should be asked on ELL Meta rather than here to find out if the site-settings have it turned off for everyone there.

I've tried to find a question here related to individual site settings that touches on this, but none turn-up, so I'm not clear if it's a quirk of the way that site's set-up or something else. Leave your question here for now until someone more knowledgeable comes along to clear this up.

Thank you. By the way, how did you find ELL Meta? I tried looking for it but ended up being here.

I think you need to type more than just one word to trigger the display of the panel. For example, try "what does inhabit"

If you go to ELL then left-click on the burger-menu top right of the screen, a dropdown will give you the site you're on, then the corresponding meta site, then some others. It doesn't work the same here on main meta because we're our own meta, so to speak.

What @PeterJames said, that works.
